# Assign value to a 2D array from a 2D array SystemVerilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

I'm quite new with SystemVerilog, I-m trying to assign a value to a 2D array from another 2D array, but each time I compile this error appers:

> Error: (vlog-13069) ../src/dadda tree/daddaTree.sv(75): near "[": syntax error, unexpected '['.

Here the code:

```
module daddaTree import globals ::*; (
    input wire signed [24:0]PP[8],
    output wire [31:0]C,
    output wire [31:0]S );

    // layers of the reduction tree
    wire [31:0]l3[8];
    wire [31:0]l2[5];

    wire [20]Tout_l3;

    // zero paffing of the inputs partial products
    assign l3[0] = 8'b00000000 & PP[0];
    assign l3[1] = 7'b0000000 & PP[1] & 1'b0;
    assign l3[2] = 6'b000000 & PP[2] & 2'b00;
    assign l3[3] = 5'b00000 & PP[3] & 3'b000;
    assign l3[4] = 4'b0000 & PP[4] & 4'b0000;
    assign l3[5] = 3'b000 & PP[5] & 5'b00000;
    assign l3[6] = 2'b00 & PP[6] & 6'b000000;
    assign l3[7] = 1'b0 & PP[7] & 7'b0000000;   // MSB for carry of the layer

        // bit with no compression
    //  [4:0]l2[0:4] = '{l3{[4:0][0:4]}};      ERRORS HERE 
    //  assign l2[5][1:4] = l3[5][2:5];
    //  assign l2[6][2:4] = l3[6][3:6];
    //  assign l2[7][3:4] = l3[7][6:7];
        

endmodule
```

I can assign an entire raw of bit as `assign l3[0] = 8'b00000000 & PP[0];`, but when I have to assign a slice of an array to another the compiler givve me the above error.

I mean how can assign for example:

> "l3 from column 0 to 4, from raw 0 to 4"

to

> "l2 from column 0 to 4, from raw 0 to 4"

as an example bits [4:0] of column [0:4] of l2 should have as input bits [4:0] of column [0:4] of l3, that are zeros, or PP values received from another module,  so unknwon values.

I can do the assignement manualy untill a certain point:

```
    // bit without compression
assign l2[0][0] = l3[0][0]; // c0

assign l2[1][0] = l3[1][0]; // c1
assign l2[1][1] = l3[1][1];

assign l2[2][0] = l3[2][0]; // c2
assign l2[2][1] = l3[2][1];
assign l2[2][2] = l3[2][2];

assign l2[3][0] = l3[3][0]; // c3
assign l2[3][1] = l3[3][1];
assign l2[3][2] = l3[3][2];
assign l2[3][3] = l3[3][3];

assign l2[4][0] = l3[4][0]; // c4
assign l2[4][1] = l3[4][1];
assign l2[4][2] = l3[4][2];
assign l2[4][3] = l3[4][3];
assign l2[4][4] = l3[4][4];

assign l2[5][1] = l3[5][2]; // c5
assign l2[5][2] = l3[5][3];
assign l2[5][3] = l3[5][4];
assign l2[5][4] = l3[5][5];
```

but also in this case an error appears

> Error (suppressible): ../src/dadda tree/daddaTree.sv(95): (vlog-2698) Index 5 into array dimension 1 of 'l2' is out of bounds.

Please someone can explain me how can I assign it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`[4:0]l2[0:4] = '{l3{[4:0][0:4]}}` -- what is it supposed to mean? No wonder that there is a syntax error. I guess, you wanted something like the following: *assign l2[0:4][4:0] = l3[0:4][4:0]* which is impossible, because you take a slice of the lower dimension here.

As for index out of bounds, l2 is declared as `wire [31:0]l2[5];` where the outer index is [5], meaning [0:4].  So, when you tried to use index *5* it is out of bounds since the max is **4**.

So, your only bet is to use *generate* for loops, for example (based on your manual code):

```
for(genvar i = 0; i <= 4; i++) begin: L1
   for (genvar j = 0; j < i; j++) begin: L2
       assign l2[i][j] = l3[i][j];
   end
end
```

Or maybe like this:

```
 for(genvar i = 0; i <= 4; i++) begin: L1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     assign l2[i][i:0] = l3[i][i:0];                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 end
```

You have to figure out exact numbers.